# How to Detect Diacritic/Umlaut characters in an XML file

Tags: xml, qt, character-encoding, xml-parsing, diacritics

I am developing a `Qt application` and we support *Localization*. I am maintaining an XML file for each language we support in TS File format. And we have many strings that we need to display on our product.

I wanted to know is there any utility (like `lupdate`) in Qt Linguist or any XML parser or tool that can parse the XML language file and detect the `Umlaut characters` (for ex: `ä`, `Ä` etc) and print that particular string - so that developer can notice how many strings we have with compound characters in it.

Any info on this will be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: "so that developer can notice how many strings we have with compound characters in it." Why do you think that the developers need to know such things?

Comment: I am developer myself, so I wanted to know how to just filter out these strings with compound characters. At the end I can discard those strings with compound characters and request for re-translation. But my language resource file is so large that it is difficult to check each string for the presence of these compound characters. So Am curious if we have some tool or application that does that for us.

Comment: Are you looking for strings in German or strings with Umlauts in them? If you want to detect untranslated German strings, then you could try  a languauge identification library like e.g. [langauge-detection](https://code.google.com/p/language-detection/). There are others, too.